# Using grep in tapply()-function for string matching in data frame in R

Tags: r, apply

I have a data frame consisting of 36 observations of 8 variables (the first two variables are factors and the last 6 are numeric). The structure looks like this:

```
Technology     Sector 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 mean
Photovoltaic   Energy  10   20   30   10   30   20             
Wind-based     Energy  20   60   60   20   40   40  
Cultivation    Nature  10   10   20   30   30   20
```

I want to be get the mean for every technology, that has the string "based" in its name. I've done it that way:

```
df[[8]][c(grep("based",Technology))]
```

And it works exactly how it is supposed to. The task from my online course is, to do it also with one of the following: apply()-, lapply()-, sapply()- or tapply()-function. How can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping functions (tapply, by, aggregate) and the \*apply family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family)

Comment: The [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family/7141669#7141669) has an excellent answer that can help you with your course assignment. Good luck!

Comment: If the task is just to subset, your way is more efficient, as it's vectorized and requires no iteration like the `*apply` functions. You con't need `c`, though; `grep` already returns a vector.

Comment: I think that the tapply()-function is relevant, but when I write this function:    tapply(df$mean,c(grep("based",Technology)),print)
an error is generated, "arguments must have same length".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `tapply` is an appropriate option because OP wants to just get a subset. Now, if it is must to use `apply/lapply/sapply...` then option could be as:

```
df$mean[mapply(function(x)grepl("based", x), df$Technology)]
#[1] 40

df$mean[sapply(df$Technology,function(x)grepl("based", x))]
#[1] 40
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text=  
"Technology     Sector 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 mean
Photovoltaic   Energy  10   20   30   10   30   20             
Wind-based     Energy  20   60   60   20   40   40  
Cultivation    Nature  10   10   20   30   30   20",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```